# How can multiply vector by a matrix using CUDA c++

Tags: c++, cuda

Can any one help me, how can I multiply vector(1*N) and matrix(N*M) and store the result on new vector(1*M) using CUDA c++.

Comment: A search or a quick browse of recent CUDA questions will reveal at least three questions about this subject, inlcuding code. Further, there is a matrix multiplication example in the CUDA SDK/examples and CUDA ships with CUBLAS. All you need to do is look for them....

Comment: [Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#matrix-multiplication--cuda-runtime-api-version-) is cuda matrix multiply sample.  [Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_7_2) is CUBLAS matrix vector multiply.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess StackOverflow is the place to ask a question and discuss solutions. While this question has been downvoted by many people, I've answered this question. Maybe the asker need some discussions on the available solutions. Here is the code intended for large `M`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <time.h>

__global__
void kernel(float *vec, float *mat, float *out, const int N, const int M){
    int tid=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
        float sum=0;
    if(tid<M){
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            sum += vec[i]*mat[(i*M)+tid];
        out[tid]=sum;
    }
}

// debuging functions
void init_array(float *a, const int N);
void init_mat(float *a, const int N, const int M);
void print_array(float *a, const int N, char *d);
void print_mat(float *a, const int N, const int M, char *d);

int main (void) {
        srand( time(NULL) );

    float *a, *b, *c;
        float *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    int N=3;
    int M=4;
    a=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*N);
    b=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*N*M);
    c=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*M);
        init_array(a, N);
        init_mat(b, N, M);
        init_array(c, M);

    printf("<<<<<<<<<< initial data:\n");
        print_array(a, N, "in-vector");
        print_mat(b, N, M, "matrix");
        print_array(c, M, "out-vector");

        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, sizeof(float)*N);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, sizeof(float)*N*M);
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(float)*M);

        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeof(float)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, sizeof(float)*N*M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printf("\n\nRunning Kernel...\n\n");
        kernel<<<M/256+1, 256>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, N, M);
        //printf("error code: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

        cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, sizeof(float)*M, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        cudaFree(dev_a);
        cudaFree(dev_b);
        cudaFree(dev_c);

    printf(">>>>>>>>>> final data:\n");
        print_array(c, M, "out-vector");

        return 0;
};

void init_array(float *a, const int N) {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                a[i] = rand() % 4 + 1;
}
void init_mat(float *a, const int N, const int M) {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
            for(j=0; j<M; j++)
                    a[i*M+j] = rand() % 4 + 1;
}
void print_array(float *a, const int N, char *d) {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                printf("\n%s[%d]: %f",d, i, a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void print_mat(float *a, const int N, const int M, char *d) {
        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("\n%s[%d]:", d, i);
        for (j=0; j<M; j++)
                    printf("\t%6.4f", a[i*M+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It needs minor modifications to suit for large `N`.

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful while learning CUDA. Thank you for providing this!

Comment: @ahmad how do you determine the block and grid size in this case scenario?